# MVC6 route choosing wrong action

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make a simple webpage with more than one parameter coming in.

When I click on the link, it takes me to /Links/Index/1/2 instead of /Links/Canvas/1/2 as expected.

Controller:

```
public class linksController : Controller
{
public IActionResult Index(int? id)
    { ...... return View() }
public IActionResult Canvas(int param1, int param2)
    { ...... return View() }
}
```

Page with the link that's not working:

```
<a asp-route="newroute" asp-route-param1="1" asp-route-param2="2">View</a>
```

Startup.cs:

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {

            routes.MapRoute(
        name: "newroute",
        template: "{controller=Links}/{action=Canvas}/{param1}/{param2}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The default values that you specified in your route are only used if there is not already a value, but when you use the route in this context those values are populated with the controller and action values of the page you are currently viewing rather than the default values.

You can override the controller and action values by changing your code to look like this:

`<a asp-controller="Links" asp-action="Canvas" asp-route-param1="1" asp-route-param2="2">View</a>`